# How can I overlap qwidgets while using the grid layout and positioning overlapping widgets a particular distance from the window border?

Tags: c++, qt

I am programming a game and I have a tab widget which takes up the majority of the window.  I want to use the extra space in the tab bar for buttons.  I have the tab widget in a grid layout.  To accomplish this, I use the code below in order to remove and add back the button widgets to the desired areas (the solution to someone else's question).

```
ui->centralLayout->removeWidget(ui->exitButton);
ui->centralLayout->removeWidget(ui->ResizeButton);
ui->centralLayout->addWidget(ui->ResizeButton,0,4, Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignRight);
ui->centralLayout->addWidget(ui->exitButton,0,4, Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignRight);
```

This does not work for me; however, because I would like the second widget-- the resize button-- to be just to the left of the exit button.  What is occurring is that it instead overlaps the exit button.  I simply need to move it 21 pixels to the left and have no idea how!

I tried putting both buttons in a frame and then removing and adding the frame the way I did the buttons.  Unfortunately the same functions I used do not exist for the qt frame object.

Here are some pictures of my window.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/17w5USWQcCtb6OdcRShdcYcRjXTcdVpmdrG5TWLX71y8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you removing stuff from a layout and adding it back to the same layout?

Comment: There is no way to make them overlap in the editor.  That is why I am creating them in the editor then changing their position.

Comment: You can just create them in the designer without adding them to a layout. You can also just create a horizontal layout in the designer, put the buttons inside that layout, and then add that layout to the grid layout.

Comment: This will not allow the buttons to overlap the bar tab like I want.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `void QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget * widget, int row, int column, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0)` overload.
2-nd and 3-rd parameters are row and column of a grid. And you put 2 widgets in the same cell so they are overlaping each other.

Comment: I noticed that; but if I use any other column value the button widgets will be outside of the tab widget's extra bar space.

Comment: I will add a link to the original post with images to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.  Earlier when I was trying to add them to a frame and reposition it I could not but using a widget as the container for my buttons let me place them the way I was earlier attempting to individually place the buttons.